# Refresh sticky mobile leaderboard ad slot by changing the content URL in infinite scroll

Tags: sticky, slot

I want to refresh sticky mobile leaderboard slot when the URL changes in infinite scroll. What do you think is the best way to go? Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
class DFPAds {
  constructor() {
    this.slots = [];
    this.onScroll = throttle(this.loopAds, 300);
    this.addEvents();

    this.createAdObject = this.createAdObject.bind(this);
    this.createSlotForAd = this.createSlotForAd.bind(this);
    this.displayAd = this.displayAd.bind(this);
  }

  static get() {
    return DFPAds._instance;
  }

  static set() {
    if (!DFPAds._instance) {
      DFPAds._instance = new DFPAds();
      return DFPAds._instance;
    } else {
      throw new Error("DFPAds: instance already initialized");
    }
  }

  addEvents() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", e => this.onScroll());
  }

  loopAds() {
    this.slots.map(slot => this.displayAd(slot));
  }

  createAdObject(ad) {     
    let id = ad.id;
    let attributes = getDataSet(ad);    
    let sizes = JSON.parse(attributes.sizes);
    let sizeMapping;

    if (attributes.sizemapping) {
      attributes.sizemapping.length
        ? (sizeMapping = JSON.parse(attributes.sizemapping))
        : (sizeMapping = null);
    }

    attributes.id = id;
    attributes.sizes = sizes;
    attributes.sizemapping = sizeMapping;

    return attributes;
  }


  createSlotForAd(adObject) {
    let {
      id,
      adtype,
      position,
      slotname,
      sizes,
      sizemapping,
      shouldlazyload,
      pagenumber,
      pageid
    } = adObject;

    googletag.cmd.push(() => {
      let slot = googletag.defineSlot(slotname, sizes, id);

      if(position){
        slot.setTargeting("position", position);
      }
      if(pagenumber){
        slot.setTargeting("pagenumber", pagenumber);
      }

      if(pageid){
        slot.setTargeting("PageID", pageid)   
      }

      if (sizemapping) {
        let mapping = googletag.sizeMapping();

        sizemapping.map(size => {
          mapping.addSize(size[0], size[1])
        });

        slot.defineSizeMapping(mapping.build());
      }

      slot.addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.display(id);

      shouldlazyload
        ? this.slots.push({ slot: slot, id: id })
        : googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);
        console.log("SlotTop", slot)
    });
  }

  displayAd(slot) {
    console.log("Slottwo", slot)
    let item = document.getElementById(slot.id);
    if (item) {
      let parent = item.parentElement;
      let index = this.slots.indexOf(slot);
      let parentDimensions = parent.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (
        (parentDimensions.top - 300) < window.innerHeight &&
        parentDimensions.top + 150 > 0 &&
        parent.offsetParent != null
      ) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
          googletag.pubads().refresh([slot.slot]);
        });
        this.slots.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }


  setUpAdSlots(context = document) {
    let ads = [].slice.call(context.getElementsByClassName("Ad-data"));
    if (ads.length) {
      ads.map(ad => compose(this.createSlotForAd, this.createAdObject)(ad));
    }
  }
}

export default DFPAds;
```

**And this is my Infinite Scroll code:**

```
export default class InfiniteScroll {
    constructor() {
        this._end = document.getElementById('InfiniteScroll-End');
        this._container = document.getElementById('InfiniteScroll-Container');
            if(!this._end || !this._container)
                return;

        this._articles = { };
        this._triggeredArticles = [];
        this._currentArticle = '';
        this._apiUrl = '';
        this._count = 1;
        this._timedOut = false;
        this._loading = false;
        this._ended = false;
        this._viewedParameter = "&alreadyViewedContentIds=";
        this._articleSelector = "InfiniteScroll-Article-";
        this._articleClass = "Article-Container";

        this.setStartData();
        this.onScroll = throttle(this.eventScroll, 200);
        this.addEvents();
    }

    addEvents(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => this.onScroll() );
        }, 2000);
    }

    addToStore(article){
        this._articles["a" + article.id] = article;
    }

    addToTriggeredArticles(id){
        this._triggeredArticles.push(id);
    }

    getRequestUrl(){
        return this._apiUrl + this._viewedParameter + Object.keys(this._articles).map(key => this._articles[key].id).join();
    }

    getLastArticle(){
        return this._articles[Object.keys(this._articles)[Object.keys(this._articles).length-1]];
    }

    setStartData() {
        let dataset = getDataSet(this._container);
        if(dataset.hasOwnProperty('apiurl')){
            let article = Article.get();
            if(article){
                this._apiUrl = dataset.apiurl;
                this._currentArticle = "a" + article.id;

                this.addToStore(article);
            }else{
                throw(new Error('Infinite Scroll: Article not initialized.'));
            }
        }else{
            throw(new Error('Infinite Scroll: Start object missing "apiurl" property.'));
        }
    }

    eventScroll() {
            if(this.isApproachingNext()){
                this.requestNextArticle();
            }

            if(!this.isMainArticle(this._articles[this._currentArticle].node)){
                this.updateCurrentArticle();
            }
    }

    eventRequestSuccess(data){
        this._loading = false;
        if(data != ''){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('Id') && data.hasOwnProperty('Html') && data.hasOwnProperty('Url')){
                this.incrementCount();
                let node = document.createElement('div');
                node.id = this._articleSelector + data.Id;
                node.innerHTML = data.Html;
                node.className = this._articleClass;
                this._container.appendChild(node);

                this.initArticleUpNext({
                    img: data.Img, 
                    title: data.ArticleTitle, 
                    category: data.Category, 
                    target: node.id 
                });

                this.addToStore(
                    new Article({
                        id: data.Id, 
                        node: node, 
                        url: data.Url, 
                        title: data.Title, 
                        count: this._count,
                        nielsenProps: {
                            section: data.NeilsenSection,
                            sega: data.NeilsenSegmentA,
                            segb: data.NeilsenSegmentB,
                            segc: data.NeilsenSegmentC
                        }
                    })
                );
            }else{
                this._ended = true;
                throw(new Error('Infinite Scroll: Response does not have an ID, Url and HTML property'));
            }
        }else{
            this._ended = true;
            throw(new Error('Infinite Scroll: No new article was received.'));
        }
    }

    eventRequestError(response){
        this._loading = false;
        this._ended = true;
        throw(new Error("Infinite Scroll: New article request failed."));
    }

    requestNextArticle(){
        if(!this._loading){
            this._loading = true;
            return API.requestJSON(this.getRequestUrl())
                .then(
                    (response)=>{this.eventRequestSuccess(response)},
                    (response)=>{this.eventRequestError(response)}
                );
        }
    }


    triggerViewEvent(article){
        if(article.count > 1 && !this.isAlreadyTriggeredArticle(article.id)){
            this.addToTriggeredArticles(article.id);
            Tracker.pushView(article.url, article.count);

            if(isFeatureEnabled('Nielsen') && Nielsen.get()){
                Nielsen.get().eventInfiniteScroll({
                    id: article.id,
                    url: article.url,
                    section: article.nielsenProps.section,
                    sega: article.nielsenProps.sega,
                    segb: article.nielsenProps.segb,
                    segc: article.nielsenProps.segc
                });
                NielsenV60.trackEvent(article.title);
            }
        }
    }

    updateCurrentArticle(){
        Object.keys(this._articles).map( key => {
            if(this._currentArticle !== key && this.isMainArticle(this._articles[key].node)){
                this._currentArticle = key;
                this.updateUrl(this._articles[key]);
                this.triggerViewEvent(this._articles[key]);
            }
        }); 
    }

    updateUrl(article){
        try{
            if(history.replaceState){
                if(window.location.pathname !== article.url){
                    history.replaceState('', article.title, article.url);
                }
            }
        }catch(e){}
    }

    incrementCount(){
        this._count = this._count + 1;
    }

    initArticleUpNext(data){
        this.getLastArticle().initUpNext(data);
    }

    isApproachingNext(){
        return window.pageYOffset  > this._end.offsetTop - (window.innerHeight * 2) && !this._ended && this._end.offsetTop >= 100;
    }

    isMainArticle(node){
        if(node.getBoundingClientRect){
            return (node.getBoundingClientRect().top < 80 && node.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 70);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    isAlreadyTriggeredArticle(id){
        return this._triggeredArticles.indexOf(id) > -1;
    }


}
```